# knitr compiling document with chinese

Tags: r, character-encoding, knitr, chinese-locale

I try compiling YiHui's BIG5 [example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/078-chinese-big5.rnw) (knitr with chinese content). I used Mac OSX snowleopard, latest RStudio, pdfLatex (same result with XeLatex). This is an excerpt of the raw .Rnw

```
\begin{document}
\title{knitr與繁體中文文檔}
\author{謝益輝}

測試，咳咳。以下代碼靠譜嗎？

<<test>>=
1+1 # 太簡單了
'引號能用嗎？'
rnorm(5)
(function(){
paste('這裡是字符串')
})()
@
```

Using the system default encoding "UTF-8" the resulting pdf is

```
1+1 #
## [1] 2
''
## [1] ""
rnorm(5)
## [1] -0.4290 1.8835 -0.7045 -0.9232 1.5433
(function(){ paste('') })()
## [1] ""
```

as you can see the chinese are just blank space. Then I saved the .Rnw with BIG5 encoding and compile again. The resulting pdf becomes:

```
AyyCHUNXaH
1+1 # F
## [1] 2
'H'
## [1] "H"
rnorm(5)
## [1] -0.27859 -0.79428 -0.76903 0.40313 -0.07851
(function(){ paste('oOr') })()
## [1] "oOr"
```

This time the chinese becomes some random letters.

What else can I do? Completely newbie w.r.t. encoding/locale.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set up Chinese fonts for XeLaTeX, which I did not do in my example because I have no idea what fonts I should use for Traditional Chinese, and it is not easy to provide a portable solution across different operating systems because I do not know what fonts are available. You may take a look at the **[xeCJK](http://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk)** package.

Comment: How to set up fonts for xelatex in rmd?

Comment: @xgdgsc You may try this package: https://github.com/rstudio/rticles https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/ctex/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may try these code below.

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="en_US.UTF-8")
```

However, it doesn't guarantee the random letter problem would be gone because I had the same problem with my R installation as well. My OS is Chinese. This problem is completely solved when I changed my OS to MAC. Hope it helps.